# Texts of Maharal’s Commentary on Shas

Tags: jewish-books, text, maharal

Does anyone happen to know where I can find online the text of the Maharal’s commentary on Shas that’s not copyright?

Comment: Are you looking for text or images?

Comment: I’m looking for text.

Answer (score 8):

You can find it on [HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/). ([Vol. 1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14194), [Vol. 2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14201), [Vol. 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14192), [Vol. 4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14199))

The work is known as *Chiddushei Agados Maharal MiPrague*.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96228/texts-of-maharal-s-commentary-on-shas?noredirect=1#comment318678_96228